# T-SQL Get SerializeValue where the name exists more than 1

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

i have the following serialize value:

```
Active=1&Time=19&Loops=2&looptype=loopcustom&CC=john@gmail.com&CC=joane@gmail.com&MyMessage=something
```

how can i get only the values of the CC.
What i mean is to get the values john@gmail.com and joane@gmail.com in 2 rows or in 2 variables.

The big problem in this is that the value always change, 
for example it can have more CC values or other parameters. 
The serialize value is dynamic and not static.

I have try to use patindex etc. but its not working because the value is not always the same.

have anyone an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure this is probably not the best approach, but it works (for your example):

```
    DECLARE @x VARCHAR(1000) = 'Active=1&Time=19&Loops=2&looptype=loopcustom&CC=john@gmail.com&CC=joane@gmail.com&MyMessage=something'


WHILE CHARINDEX('CC',@x) <> 0  
BEGIN

    SELECT SUBSTRING(@X, 
              CHARINDEX('CC=',@X)+3,
              CHARINDEX('&',@X,CHARINDEX('CC=',@X)) - (CHARINDEX('CC=',@X)+3) ) 

    SELECT @x = SUBSTRING(@X,CHARINDEX('&',@X,CHARINDEX('CC=',@X)),LEN(@X))

END
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert it to xml:

```
DECLARE @txt varchar(2000) = 'Active=1&Time=19&Loops=2&looptype=loopcustom&CC=john@gmail.com&CC=joane@gmail.com&MyMessage=something'

SELECT 
  STUFF(t.c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(2000)'), 1, 3, '')
FROM (
    SELECT x = CAST('<t>' + 
        REPLACE(@txt, '&', '</t><t>') + '</t>' AS XML)
) a
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/t') t(c)
WHERE 
  t.c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(2000)') like 'CC=%'
```

Result:

```
john@gmail.com
joane@gmail.com
```